# Inexplicable white space on right of web-page. Causes horizontal scroll bar to appear

Tags: html, css

A fun game:

```
http://revelry-cycles.com/index.html
```

go to that site, identify the reason behind the white space on the right hand side.

I have been playing this game for an hour or so and I am sick of it! I have used Chrome's Object Identifier and there is NOTHING there.

Comment: Set your `body` to `overflow-x: hidden`. Your vertical scrollbar is probably adding about `19px` of whitespace to the right of your page. Post your code here and maybe a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you or your costructive reply JakeGould.

Comment: As for gaynorvader, 

There is something like a few hundred pixels of whitespace showing down the right of the page, and no tools I have used can locate ANYTHING taking up any of that space at all.

Comment: Please post the CSS you have applied to your HTML and BODY tags.  If you resize the browser enough it eventually goes away so you must have a width applied somewhere.

Comment: It's your carousel/slide-show.

Comment: Ok, I shall attempt to change some CSS on that immediatly. If you can see Where or why its my slideshow post it as an answer so I can tick you :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was not easy to identify, but I'm now pretty sure it's the label "Select bike part". By using tools like Firebug you can see that the element `#bbLabel` is too wide and thus causing the overflow. The problem is that you didn't change its width, so it still has the default of 100% of the 800px page width, while at the same time a relative offset of 60% to the right is applied. If you add the style rule `width: 40%` to the `#bbLabel` the problem is solved.

Comment: Almost identical timing on 2 solutions. both right, this one has a little more explanation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

On the off-chance someone else has the same problem:

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <!--content-->
       <!--carousel-->
       <!--more content-->
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
#content
{
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;/*This means the content is centered on the page*/
}
```

The fact that the images in the carousel were arranged like this:

```
Content:       Rest of page:
|[Current Img]|[Next Img][3rd Image][Final Image]
```

meant that the page was pushed out to the right, resulting in the appearance of the horizontal scrollbar. The easiest solution is to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the style for the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Na dude, tried this. no good. the images stack below each other not next to each other. it has a max width.

if i put any Overflow hiddens in i get a wierd secodn scroll bar.. go look at your solution on my site.

Comment: I don't see my solution on your site, however, when I put `overflow-x: hidden` on your body tag through the f12 menu, it works. If you open up the F12 tools and navigate to `<ul class="bxslider">` you can see that it is over `4000px` wide, also if you hover over the `li` chrome will highlight them to the right of your content div.

Answer (score 1):

The element causing the whitespace is `#bbLabel`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I cannot believe I didn't check the builder!

Comment: @NicholasBarker You're welcome, although I think you should accept matthias.p's answer, he gave a more detailed explanation and was 4 seconds faster. :)

Comment: Have done so! i think the comment time must have displayed wrong as I definatly got yours first.